# JavaScript - Is there a way to merge 2 objects by a specified key property?

Tags: javascript, node.js

JavaScript - Is there a way to merge 2 objects by a specified key property? The key property in this case is the `authorId`.

> **NOTE:** author 3 and author 1 don't have matches, so they shouldn't get merged.

```
var b = [{"book": "book1", "authorId": 3},{"book": "book2", "authorId":2}];

var a = [{"authorId": 1, "author": "author1"},{"authorId": 2, "author": "author2"}];

var c = a.merge(b);

console.log(c);
```

**expecting:**

```
[{"book": "book2", "authorId": 2, "author": "author2"}]
```

> I'm trying to accomplish here what a SQL JOIN does.

https://jsfiddle.net/x67fpwoj/4/

Answer (score 2):

`map` by `Object.assign` from the item in the other array with the same index:

```js
var b = [{"book": "book1", "authorId": 1},{"book": "book2", "authorId":2}];
var a = [{"authorId": 1, "author": "author1"},{"authorId": 2, "author": "author2"}];
var c = a.map((aItem, i) => Object.assign({}, aItem, b[i]));
console.log(c);
```

If you can't count on each array being ordered, then you might `reduce` into an object indexed by `authorId`, and then get that object's values (this has `O(N)` complexity rather than a `.find` on each iteration, which would have `O(N^2)` complexity):

```js
var a = [{"authorId": 1, "author": "author1"},{"authorId": 2, "author": "author2"}];
var b = [{"book": "book1", "authorId": 1},{"book": "book2", "authorId":2}];

const reduceByAuthor = (arr, initial = {}) => arr.reduce((a, item) => {
  a[item.authorId] = Object.assign((a[item.authorId] || {}), item);
  return a;
}, initial);

const indexedByAuthor = reduceByAuthor(a);
reduceByAuthor(b, indexedByAuthor);
console.log(Object.values(indexedByAuthor));
```

If you *also* can't count on each item having a match in the other array, then `reduce` twice, with the second `reduce` assigning to the accumulator only if a match was found in the first indexed object (quicker than `filtering` afterwards):

```js
var b = [{"book": "book1", "authorId": 3},{"book": "book2", "authorId":2}];
var a = [{"authorId": 1, "author": "author1"},{"authorId": 2, "author": "author2"}];

const aIndexed = a.reduce((a, item) => {
  a[item.authorId] = item;
  return a;
}, {});
const c = Object.values(b.reduce((a, bItem) => {
  const { authorId } = bItem;
  const aItem = aIndexed[authorId];
  if (aItem) a[authorId] = Object.assign({}, aItem, bItem);
  return a;
}, {}))

console.log(c);
```

Comment: I don't see where `authorId` is specified. How do it know how to join?

Comment: Because the `i`th item in the `a` array corresponds to the `i`th item in the `b` array already (as in your example), there's no need to check for that - you can just merge the `i`th item from each array together.

Comment: uses `return Object.assign({}, aItem, b.find(bItem => bItem.authorId = aItem.authorId))` should be better...

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not what the asker is looking for.  This assumes the ordering is exactly correct and doesn't actually merge these two arrays intelligently.

Comment: @Rod If your input isn't necessarily ordered, please edit your question or its example to clarify such.

Comment: Ok, I updated the OP to be more clear (sorry about that). So, now note the expected has changed.

Comment: @Rod uses the initial solution of the answer, add some codes then will get the result. like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x67fpwoj/8/); if care about performance, you need to build index (uses dictionary) like the real database does.

Comment: @Sphinx The reason I didn't want to use a `find` inside another iterator is because it has (unnecessary) `O(N^2)` complexity

Comment: I apologize everyone for being unclear, thanks for your patience and sticking with it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Hah, I know... uses the reduce in your answer already done it. I just want to tell the OP, your initial answer almost reach the goal.

Comment: @Sphinx @CertainPerformance Just noting that using an index could be less performant than using a find depending on the situation. Say `a` contains items `[1, 2, 4]` and `b`has items `[1...1000]`. Building the index for `b` would need to loop 1000 times before looping over `a` whereas a `find` in the loop for each item of `a` would be 1 for `1`, 2 for `2`, and then 4 for `4` for a total of 7 loops. In a DB this isn't a concern as the index is held in memory and reused but odds here that this wouldn't be the case and it would be rebuilt for each invocation.

Comment: @JasonCust If the arrays happen to be so mismatched and ordered just right, `.find` *could* take less time, but that's not likely unless the items to be found are generally in the first few indicies of the larger array *and* the first array doesn't contain any items that are missing in the second array.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Agreed. I just wanted to mention that it shouldn't be a forgone conclusion unless you understand your data sets. 

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to specify the field to join on (since you mentioned SQL like syntax) and without worrying too much about performance (if it is then you would need to build an index for the object to be merged from but read the perf note below) then you can use a couple of array methods and a destructuring assignment to merge the object arrays.

```js
const b = [{"book": "book1", "authorId": 3},{"book": "book2", "authorId":2}];

const a = [{"authorId": 1, "author": "author1"},{"authorId": 2, "author": "author2"}];

// Using reduce will allow filtering of unmatched records
const merge = (field, x, z) => x.reduce((out, v) => {
  // Make sure the field exists in the object to merge
  // Using find will return the first object that matches the criteria (multiple record matching was not mentioned as a concern in the OP)
  const match = v.hasOwnProperty(field) && z.find((c) => c[field] === v[field]);
  
  if (match) {
    // Only push onto the output array if there is a match
    // Use destructuring assignment to merge the matching objects
    out.push({...v, ...match});
  }

  return out;
}, []);

console.log(merge('authorId', a, b));
```

**Perf Note:** Be wary with using an index approach for a variety of reasons. For instance when the object to key the merge from is very small compared to the data set to merge with. Building the index might take longer then just searching the array for the relatively small number of matches. You should use them when it makes sense but just noting that it shouldn't be a flat statement to do so.

For completeness, here is the same code with a temp index:

```js
const b = [{"book": "book1", "authorId": 3},{"book": "book2", "authorId":2}];

const a = [{"authorId": 1, "author": "author1"},{"authorId": 2, "author": "author2"}];

const merge = (field, x, z) => {
  const index = z.reduce((out, v) => {
    if (v.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
      out[v[field]] = v;
    }
    
    return out;
  }, {});
  
  return x.reduce((out, v) => {
    const match = index[v[field]];

    if (match) {
      out.push({...v, ...match});
    }

    return out;
  }, []);
};

console.log(merge('authorId', a, b));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you need with clear code:

```
var c = [];
b.map(item1 => {
  a.map(item2 => {
    if (item1.authorId === item2.authorId) {
      c.push(Object.assign(item1, item2));
    }
  })
});
console.log(c);
```

Comment: I don't know why ?!

Comment: @Rod It might be due to the performance concern here of iterating over every item in `a` for every iteration of `b`. This would not a recommended solution.